# Infinite-dimensional product space series and projections

Tags: linear-algebra

$\ell_2$ is an infinite-dimensional inner product space consisting of all infinite sequences of the form $(x_1,x_2,\ldots) $ satisfying that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2 = x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots$ converges. Given $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2,\ldots)$ in $\ell_2$, $\ell_2$ has the inner product: $\langle x,y \rangle = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_ny_n = x_1y_1+x_2y_2+\cdots$ which is also an infinite series.

Given the two sequences in $\ell_2: x=(1,\frac23,\frac49,\frac8{27},\ldots) $ and $ y (1,\frac34,\frac49,\frac{27}{64},...)$

1. Find $\langle x,y \rangle$, $\|x\|$,$\|y\|$
2. Let $S$ be the subspace of $\ell_2$ spanned by $x$. Find $\operatorname{proj}_s y$ and $\operatorname{proj}_{s^\perp}y$ (as in the projection of $y$ onto $S$ and the projection of $y$ onto $S^\perp$

Doing Part 1 is fairly easy, I got that $\langle x,y \rangle=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac12)^{n-1}$ which is just 2, $\|x\|^2=\langle x,x\rangle=\frac95$,and $\|y\|^2=\langle y,y\rangle =\frac{16}7$, but I have no clue how to even start Part 2. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How would you do those two projections using those three inner products in a finite dimensional vector space.

Comment: I don't see how your part 1 calculations are even correct. For instance, why is $\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$? If we multiply $x_3y_3$ we get $\frac{16}{81}$ which is not a reciprocal power of $2$; also the series should at least start at $n=0$ to account for $x_1y_1=1$.

Comment: Should $y_3$ be $\frac{9}{16}$?

Comment: $x3y3= 8/27 * 27/64 = 8/64 = 1/8 = (1/2)^3$

Comment: Also changed to to the n-1, the inner product starts at n=1 so I was keeping the same format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in finite dimension geometry you have:
$$\operatorname{proj}_S y = \langle y,x \rangle \frac{x}{\Vert x \Vert^2}$$
and:
$$\operatorname{proj}_{S^\perp} y = y-\operatorname{proj}_{S} y$$

Comment: but what is $x$ in this case? just $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(\frac23)^{n-1}?$

Comment: $x$ is the vector of $l^2$ given in your question.